# Why do post edits sometimes contain the same text?

Tags: support

I've been noticing for a while what some edits do not actually edit something. [As in this post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/205176/revisions) I understand "Dr." being changed to "Doctor", but there's also "spiritual" and "metaphysical" seem to be edited, but nothing actually changed.
[image]

What is the reason for that?

Comment: Switch to side-by-side markdown mode and you'll see the difference immediately

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is usually due to a markdown change.

In this specific example I removed a couple of the `>` that get inserted in the middle of a sentence when you click "Insert quote" button. You can see this if you review the side-by-side markdown version.

[image: Image showing markdown revision differences]

As for why I did this, well, it's easier to edit a sentence when it's all on one line and doesn't have the `>` in the middle.